# How to allow a module to use a super module's private structs in its public functions?

Tags: module, rust

I have two modules. I have a function in `generate` that I want to call from my crate root, but I'm having some difficulty.

```
mod generate {
    use crate::TADRMatrix;

    pub fn generate() -> Vec<TADRMatrix> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

struct TADRMatrix;

fn main() {
    generate::generate();
}
```

When I try compiling, I get an error:

```
error[E0446]: private type `TADRMatrix` in public interface
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 | /     pub fn generate() -> Vec<TADRMatrix> {
5 | |         unimplemented!()
6 | |     }
  | |_____^ can't leak private type
...
9 |   struct TADRMatrix;
  |   - `TADRMatrix` declared as private
```

If I take away the `pub` I get this other error:

```
error[E0603]: function `generate` is private
  --> src/main.rs:12:15
   |
12 |     generate::generate();
   |               ^^^^^^^^ this function is private
   |
note: the function `generate` is defined here
  --> src/main.rs:4:5
   |
4  |     fn generate() -> Vec<TADRMatrix> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I think the problem is that `generate` is not a proper submodule of the crate root — if it was, it should be able to access the structs without issue.

I'm not sure if that's the real reason, or if it is, how to fix it.

Comment: `TADRMatrix` has to be public as well: `pub struct TADRMatrix {`

Comment: what if I don't want any of the functions or structs public? I just want to call generate, while holding the generate function and the structs/functions it calls in a separate file so as to not clutter main.rs?

Comment: In the short run, you can replace the `use` statement with `pub type TADRMatrix = crate::TADRMatrix;` but this will trigger a deprecation warning and will probably eventually become an error…

Comment: Or you can put the definition of `TADRMatrix` in another (private) module and have it be public from the pov of this module: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=075063cc15c428c2d8066ae0f0c2ea03)

Comment: yeah, any of these work really. Even an include! macro rather than modules will work. I'm not too familiar with modularizing code so I thought I'd educate myself.